# Convert any Form Video into RGB24 Media

Tags: visual-c++, directshow

how to convert YUY2,YUV, RGB565 and More Video subtype into RGB24 Subtype Video in DirectShow + VC++

can u understand my question?

I have a Upstream filter its output is in YUY2 Format but i need to convert it into RGB24 Format.

Is there any inbuilt Filters in DirectShow or we have to convert it through my code.

i have already added ColorSpaceConverter But it is not Connecting with Smart Tee Input Pin.

Answer (score 0):

Your Input pin should accept only RGB24 media types, this way DirectShow will automatically add [Color Space Convert filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa926076.aspx) and will give you the data in RGB format.